# Pass User Id through Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'll preface my questions by saying I am certainly not a programmer... but I am trying to build a membership site and would like to display the following function/shortcode I have by user id on their profile page. This shortcode currently shows all information not specific to a user and the membership plugin I am using uses the base WP user id. Any insight on how I can pass the ID through the shortcode?

```
function view_events_by_user($args, $format='', $user_id)
{
    $args = (array) $args;
    $args['ajax'] = isset($args['ajax']) ? $args['ajax']:(!defined('EM_AJAX') || EM_AJAX );
    $args['format'] = ($format != '' || empty($args['format'])) ? $format : $args['format'];
    $args['format'] = html_entity_decode($args['format']); //shortcode doesn't accept html
    $args['limit'] = isset($args['limit']) ? $args['limit'] : get_option('dbem_events_default_limit');
    if( empty($args['format']) && empty($args['format_header']) && empty($args['format_footer']) ){
        ob_start();
        if( !empty($args['ajax']) ){ echo '<div class="em-search-ajax">'; } //open AJAX wrapper
        em_locate_template('templates/events-list.php', true, array('args'=>$args));
        if( !empty($args['ajax']) ) echo "</div>"; //close AJAX wrapper
        $return = ob_get_clean();
    }else{
        $args['ajax'] = false;
        $pno = ( !empty($args['pagination']) && !empty($_GET['pno']) && is_numeric($_GET['pno']) )? $_GET['pno'] : 1;
        $args['page'] = ( !empty($args['pagination']) && !empty($args['page']) && is_numeric($args['page']) )? $args['page'] : $pno;
        $return = EM_Events::output( $args );
    }
    return $return;
}
add_shortcode ( 'view_events', 'view_events_by_user');
```

Comment: did you try `get_the_id()` ?

Comment: wouldn't it be `get_current_user_id()`? `get_the_id()` would probably give you the page ID

Comment: So get current user isn't exactly what I am trying to do...I want the logged in user to be able to view the info of any user's profile they are viewing (ie. not their own information). So if member id 1 is viewing member id 2's profile page, they would only see the events (or posts) that member 2 has published.